# Symbolicating Cocoa Mac App crash log

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a Mac app on Mac App Store, I get the following crash in iTunes Connect. I don't have the dSYM file but I do have the MyApp.app from which the error comes. Is there some way I can symbolicate the following trace:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   ...xyz.myapp                0x00000001000078da 0x100000000 + 30938
1   ...xyz.myapp                0x000000010000a38a 0x100000000 + 41866
2   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff809c392e -[NSDocument writeToURL:ofType:error:] + 727
3   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff809bfcec -[NSDocument writeToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:originalContentsURL:error:] + 432
4   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff809c3bd2 -[NSDocument _writeSafelyToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:error:] + 281
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff809c2fd0 -[NSDocument writeSafelyToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:error:] + 359
6   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff809be356 -[NSDocument saveToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:error:] + 168
7   ...xyz.myapp                0x0000000100001c22 0x100000000 + 7202
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff809c1404 -[NSDocument _saveToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:delegate:didSaveSelector:contextInfo:] + 85
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff809be637 -[NSDocument saveToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:delegate:didSaveSelector:contextInfo:] + 683
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff809c077c -[NSDocument _savePanelWasPresented:withResult:inContext:] + 367
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff80b3035e -[NSSavePanel _didEndSheet:returnCode:contextInfo:] + 75
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff808d4d45 -[NSApplication endSheet:returnCode:] + 321
13  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff807e6eda -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 95
14  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff807e6e39 -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 94
15  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8087284b -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 1715
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff808a337a -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 555
17  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff808712f5 -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 624
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8078b3a7 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 5409
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff806c0afa -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 4719
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff806576de -[NSApplication run] + 474
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff806503b0 NSApplicationMain + 364
22  …xyz.myapp          0x0000000100001794 0x100000000 + 6036
```

I open the archive from Organizer using Show in finder -> Open package contents buy the dSYMs directory doesn't contain anything. Is it possible it is somewhere else? I created the archive using Xcode Menu -> Product -> Archive and Debug Information Format is set to Dwarf with DSym

Comment: You cannot Symbolicate a crash log without dSYM file.

Comment: Presumably you created an archive when you uploaded your app to the app store. The dSYM file should be in that archive.

Comment: I open the archive from Organizer using Show in finder -> Open package contents buy the dSYMs directory doesn't contain anything. Is it possible it is somewhere else? I created the archive using Xcode Menu -> Product -> Archive and Debug Information Format is set to Dwarf with DSym

Comment: You might be able to generate the .dSYM with `dsymutil`.

Comment: *If* the application in the archive contains the debugging symbols. If not, `dsymutil` will have nothing to extract. If the debugging symbols are lost, then they are lost forever, and you will simply be unable to symbolicate this crash log.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the dSYM file. When you used Xcode to submit your application it will create an archive in your Xcode organizer. The archive also contains the dSYM information. Just right-click the archive you submitted and select "Reveal in Finder".